AWS Lambda / CRUD operations gateway blocked by CORS policy problem
I am trying to implement CRUD opretaions to my Lambda with API Gateway, you can see the implementations of my tools and the error. Even the headers are matched correct I still get the access errors
Structure of API Gateway



Here are my lambda functions
todosHandler
    const {
  DynamoDBClient,
  QueryCommand,
  PutItemCommand,
  UpdateItemCommand,
  DeleteItemCommand,
} = require("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb");
const { marshall, unmarshall } = require("@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb");

const client = new DynamoDBClient({ region: process.env.AWS_REGION });

function respond(statusCode, body) {
  return {
    statusCode,
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
        "Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET,PUT,DELETE",
    },
  };
}

function isCors(event) {
  return (event?.httpMethod || "").toLowerCase() === "options";
}

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  console.log("Received event:", JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

  if (isCors(event)) {
    return respond(200, {});
  }

  try {
    switch (event.httpMethod) {
      case "GET":
        return await handleRequest(getTodos, event);
      case "POST":
        return await handleRequest(createTodo, event);
      case "PUT":
        return await handleRequest(updateTodo, event);
      case "DELETE":
        return await handleRequest(deleteTodo, event);
      default:
        return respond(400, { message: "Unsupported method" });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error processing request:", err);
    return respond(500, { error: "Could not process request" });
  }
};

const handleRequest = async (handler, event) => {
  try {
    return await handler(event);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error in handler:", err);
    throw err;
  }
};

const getTodos = async (event) => {
  console.log("Handling GET request:", JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

  const userId = event.queryStringParameters.userId;
  const params = {
    TableName: "todos",
    KeyConditionExpression: "userId = :userId",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: marshall({ ":userId": userId }),
  };

  const data = await client.send(new QueryCommand(params));
  console.log("Query successful:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
  return respond(
    200,
    data.Items.map((item) => unmarshall(item))
  );
};

const createTodo = async (event) => {
  console.log("Handling POST request:", JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

  const todo = JSON.parse(event.body);
  const params = {
    TableName: "todos",
    Item: marshall(todo),
  };

  await client.send(new PutItemCommand(params));
  console.log("Todo created successfully");
  return respond(201, { message: "Todo created successfully" });
};

const updateTodo = async (event) => {
  console.log("Handling PUT request:", JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

  const { todoId, userId, ...updates } = JSON.parse(event.body);
  const updateExpression = [];
  const expressionAttributeValues = {};

  for (const key in updates) {
    if (updates[key] !== undefined) {
      updateExpression.push(`${key} = :${key}`);
      expressionAttributeValues[`:${key}`] = updates[key];
    }
  }

  const params = {
    TableName: "todos",
    Key: marshall({ todoId, userId }),
    UpdateExpression: `set ${updateExpression.join(", ")}`,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: marshall(expressionAttributeValues),
    ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW",
  };

  const data = await client.send(new UpdateItemCommand(params));
  console.log("Todo updated successfully:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
  return respond(200, unmarshall(data.Attributes));
};

const deleteTodo = async (event) => {
  console.log("Handling DELETE request:", JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

  const { todoId, userId } = JSON.parse(event.body);
  const params = {
    TableName: "todos",
    Key: marshall({ todoId, userId }),
  };

  await client.send(new DeleteItemCommand(params));
  console.log("Todo deleted successfully");
  return respond(200, { message: "Todo deleted successfully" });
};

the error of todos
 {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": {
        "statusCode": 400,
        "body": "{\"message\":\"Unsupported method\"}",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET,PUT,DELETE"
        }
    }
}

Mapping Teamplate for Integration Response for GET
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": $input.json('$')
}

Mapping Teamplate for Integration Request for GET
{
  "queryStringParameters": {
    "userId": "$input.params('userId')"
  }
}


Below are some steps to troubleshoot the issue

Ensure CORS is enabled for every method in API Gateway.
Verify that the method in API Gateway is linked to the correct lambda Function.
Try adding more logging at the start and end in lambda like the event data received, response created, etc.
Use both the Postman and network/console tab in your browser developer tools to check the full request/response details and errors.
Make sure to deploy changes after making any modification to API in the correct stage.


All of them checked. It looks like the isue about the IAM protocols again like I tried to do in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/78561422/14982006
